# Topology: A Categorical Approach, Exercise 0.3 d), e)

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, solution-verification

**Exercise:**

> [image]

**My attempt:**

I am not able to find examples for either d) or e), but I have some theories about what I might be looking for.

Regarding d), in $\mathsf{Top}$ the morphisms are continuous functions between topological spaces. I need a continuous function $f \colon X \to Y$ that is left- and right-cancellative yet not a homeomorphism. Since left- and right-cancellative means injective and surjective (for functions, at least), such a function $f$ will necessarily be bijective. Therefore I am looking for a continuous bijection $f \colon X \to Y$ such that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Regarding e), a comment on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32368/is-monomorphism-going-in-both-directions-sufficient-for-isomorphism) said I could consider $(0, 1)$ and $[0, 1]$ from $\mathsf{Top}$, but the level of discussion there is a bit above my pay grade. I suppose the morphism between the two was considered obvious, but I don't know what it would be. I figure that I need an injective, continuous function each way, such that there cannot be a continuous bijection each way.

I appreciate any help.

**Edit:**

Now I am confused regarding e). Since continuity preserves compactness, doesn't that mean there is no morphism of any kind $[0, 1] \to (0, 1)$?

Comment: Regarding e), are you familiar with the constructions used to show, for example, that any two open intervals $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ in $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: @LeeMosher No, but you've jogged my memory, and I'm looking at Elementary Analysis by Ross, which I read (partly) a while ago, and there is an exercise asking me to show that there is no continuous function mapping $[0, 1]$ onto $(0, 1)$. I guess that's pretty relevant here?

Comment: Not obvious if that's the right result to use. I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: d) Yes, that’s right. There is a somewhat famous example involving a half-open interval and $S^1$. e) For $(0, 1)$ and $[0, 1]$ all the functions you need are basically linear. Don’t think too hard about it.

Comment: For continuous bijections whose inverses are not continuous, a great source of examples is obtained by taking two topologies $\tau$ and $\tau'$ on the same set $X$ with $\tau\subseteq \tau'$. Then $1_X : (X,\tau')\to (X,\tau)$ is a continuous bijection of topological spaces, whose inverse is continuous precisely when $\tau=\tau'$.

Comment: Regarding your edit, no there are tons of continuous functions $[0,1]\to (0,1).$ The correct fact you state doesn't prohibit such a thing, it just says the image of such a function is compact. What it would prohibit (on the grounds that $(0,1)$ is not compact) is a continuous *surjective* function.

Comment: Also regarding your edit: constant functions are always continuous (exercise).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for your help. Too many half-formed thoughts floating around in my head. I guess a constant function $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous because the preimage of any open set in $Y$ is either $\emptyset$ or $X$? Also, would you say Sebastian Cor's answer at least regarding e) is roughly consistent with what you had in mind? I'm still trying to grasp this. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that’s right. So between any two topological spaces you always have at least the constant functions (and sometimes this is best possible). And yes, Sebastian’s answer is what I had in mind for e).

Comment: @jgon I've been trying to understand your comment. Essentially the function is continuous one way because any set in $\tau$ is contained in $\tau'$, but the inverse cannot be continuous because $\tau'$ contains sets that $\tau$ does not contain. Is that the gist of it? A beautifully simple construction. Thank you.

Comment: @Novice Yep, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **d)** think of any topological space $X$ with a topology $\tau$ that is not indiscrete then the identity function $id:(X,\tau)\to (X,I(X))$ satisfies the conditions.

For **e)** notice that any embedding $[0,1]\to (0,1)$ (for example the lineal bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]$) and the inclusion $(0,1)\hookrightarrow[0,1]$ are two monomorphisms but the sets are clearly not homeomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand your answer for e). For d), I don't understand your notation. What is $I(X)$? Based on other comments I'm guessing you are constructing the identity function from a finer topology to a coarser topology (as jgon did in his comment to my question).

Comment: $I(X)$ stands for indiscrete topology.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed true that a monomorphism in $\mathbf{Top}$ is an injection, because this holds in $\mathbf{Set}$ and we can give any set the discrete in the domain or indiscrete topology in the comomain and make any function between sets a morphism in $\mathbf{Top}$ etc.

So in $\mathbf{Top}$ $f$ is a monomorphism iff $f$ is an injective continuous function, and $f$ is an epimorphism iff $f$ is a surjective continuous function.

A standard example of a continuous bijection $f:A \to B$ between spaces that is not a homeomorphism is to take any set $X$ of two or more points, where $A = (X, \mathscr{P}(X))$ (the discrete topology on $X$) and $B=(X,\{\emptyset,X\})$ (the indiscrete topology on $X$) and $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in X$.

Then this is not an isomorphism in $\mathbf{Top}$ (i.e. a homeomorphism) because $A$ is Hausdorff and $B$ is not or simply because $f$ is not an open map (a singleton in $A$ is open and its image in $B$ is not etc.).

In $\mathbf{Top}$ we can even have continuous bijections $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$ and still $X$ and $Y$ being non-homeomorphic, see e.g. [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30661/2060) old question on Mathoverflow.

Or more simply $X = [0,1]$ and $Y = (0,1)$ in the Euclidean topology both. One is compact, the other is not, so not homeomorphic (not isomorphic in $\mathbf{Top}$).

$X$ embeds into $Y$ via $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}x$ e.g. and $Y$ is even a subspace of $X$ so $i(x)=x$ will do.

Comment: In $\bf Top$ the epimorphisms are the continuous maps with *dense range*. E.g. the inclusion $\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: @Berci only in the full subcategory $\mathbf{HausTop}$, in $\bf Top$ we need surjectivity.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes, indeed, you're right.