# Proving that $f^{-1} \in \operatorname{Hom}(Y,X).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to prove this question:

If $X,Y$ are groups and $f\in \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ is bijective, then $f^{-1} \in \operatorname{Hom}(Y,X).$ Could anyone tell me how to start, please?

The point is that my professor defined $f\in \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ to be an isomorphism if it is bijective and $f^{-1} \in \operatorname{Hom}(Y,X)$ and he said in groups it is enough to say bijective and to convince us with that he gave us the above problem to try to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to show that $f^{-1}(xy)=f^{-1}(x)f^{-1}(y)$. Since $f$ is bijective, there exists unique $u,v\in X$ such that $f(u)=x,f(v)=y$, we deduce that $f^{-1}(x)=u, f^{-1}(v)=y$. Since $f$ is a morphism of group, $f(uv)=f(u)f(v)=xy$ implies that $f^{-1}(xy)=uv=f^{-1}(x)f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: but why this is not correct in case of other categories different from groups?

Comment: Let $C$ be a category, how you define the fact that $Hom_C(X,Y)$ is bijective ?

Comment: I do not know, I am very new to Category theory.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is bijective, you know $f^{-1}$ exists. Prove that $f^{-1}$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: but why this is not correct in case of other categories different from groups?

Comment: Your question was about $\mathsf{Grp}$. If I understand you correctly you are now asking why it is not automatically true in any category that a bijective morphism $f \colon X \to Y$ has $f^{-1}$ as a morphism going the other way. I'm not sure I can explain why, but I did get some examples when I asked this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825131/topology-a-categorical-approach-exercise-0-3-d-e. Long story short: in $\mathsf{Top}$ there are continuous bijections whose inverses are not continuous.

Comment: yeah but does not continuous means not homomorphism ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In $\mathsf{Top}$, the morphisms are continuous functions. The isomorphisms are the continuous bijections with continuous inverses. It's a stronger condition.

Comment: I am understanding what you said in topology and I know that. I just want to understand the answer of my question in category theory. Below the other answer @Tsemo asked me how I define the fact that $Hom_{C}(X,Y)$ is bijective  for category $C,$could you please help me in answering that question? I have no clear definition in my mind.

Comment: I don't see how the question makes sense. The hom set is (in a locally small category) a set. It doesn't make sense to speak of a set being bijective.

Comment: @Math $\mathbf{Grp}$ is defined to include *all possible* homomorphisms. Most categories don't have such requirements. So, since isomorphism implies that an inverse homomorphism exists, you know that $\mathbf{Grp}$ contains it.