# Define the fact that $Hom_{C}(X,Y)$ is bijective for category $C.$

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

In completion to my question here:

[Proving that $f^{-1} \in \operatorname{Hom}(Y,X).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836601/proving-that-f-1-in-operatornamehomy-x/3836605?noredirect=1#comment7913224_3836605)

I know that: If $X,Y$ are groups and $f\in \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ is bijective, then $f^{-1} \in \operatorname{Hom}(Y,X).$

**My question is:**

**Why this statement is not correct in other categories than groups? could anyone help me answer this question, please?**

In helping me answering my previous question @Tsemo in the previous question asked me that question:

how we define the fact that $Hom_{C}(X,Y)$ is bijective  for category $C,$could you please help me in answering that question? I have no clear definition in my mind.

**EDIT:**

My confusion arises from the definition of **Isomorphism** that my professor gave to us, he said:

$f\in \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ is as isomorphism if it is  bijective and $f^{-1} \in \operatorname{Hom}(Y,X).$

He added that: in the category of groups $f\in \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ is as isomorphism if it is  bijective only.

This what confuses me, because I used to know that Isomorphism means homomorphism and bijection.

Comment: “Bijective” doesn’t really make sense in a category.  “Isomorphism” does, in which case the result follows directly from the axioms.

Comment: I do not understand you @Randall could you please explain more details?

Comment: What constitutes a morphism is category dependent. For example, suppose morphisms were differentiable functions. Then $f(x)=x^3$ is a differentiable bijection whose inverse is not a morphism.

Comment: Do you have an answer to my main question @Randall? sorry for my stupidness.

Comment: In the category of topological spaces, there are many bijective continuous functions whose inverse is not continuous. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378717/finding-counterexamples-bijective-continuous-functions-that-are-not-homeomorphi

Comment: There is no definition of bijective in an abstract category.   Not all categories have functions as morphisms.

Comment: @JulianRosen Yeah I know that, but we are here speaking about homomorphism not continuity ..... I do not see any relation between a function being homomorphism and it is being continous.

Comment: The morphisms in the category of topological spaces are continuous functions.

Comment: @JohnDouma that make sense ..... can you give me an example whose inverse is not homomorphism?

Comment: that make sense ..... can you give me an example whose inverse is not homomorphism?@JulianRosen

Comment: The question that I linked gives a couple examples of continuous bijections whose inverse is not continuous. One example: take $Y$ to be any non-discrete space, let $X$ have the same underlying set as $Y$ but with the discrete topology, and let $f:X\to Y$ be the identity function.

Comment: @Smart20 In category theory we write $\textrm{Hom}(X, Y)$ for the set of morphisms from $X$ to $Y$ without regard to whether or not such morphisms are called homomorphisms or not.

Comment: @ZhenLin ohhh that removes my confusion ..... thanks alot Zhen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a category $\mathcal C$, a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is called an *isomorphism* if there is a morphism $g:Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f = 1_X$ and $f\circ g = 1_Y$.

If your category is [concrete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category), i.e.

- objects are sets with extra stuff (e.g. groups, spaces),
- morphisms are stuff-preserving functions (e.g. homomorphisms, continuous functions),

then, unwrapping the definition, a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism iff it has an inverse ($f^{-1}:Y\to X$) preserving the extra stuff ($f\in\hom(Y,X)$, i.e. not just a bijection).

Your teacher proved the following:

**Fact.**
In the category of groups and homomorphisms between them, a (homo)morphism $f:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism iff its a bijection.
In other words, the set-theoretic inverse $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is already a homomorphism.

This does not occur in general:

**Fact.**
In the category of spaces and continuous functions, there are bijections which are not homeomorphisms.
For instance, if $X$ has nonequivalent topologies $\mathcal O_1, \mathcal O_2$ then the identity $id:(X,\mathcal O_1)\to (X,\mathcal O_2)$ is a bijection, but not an homeomorphism. [Example.](https://planetmath.org/exampleofcontinuousbijectionswhicharenothomeomorphisms)

**Fact.**
In the category of smooth manifodls and smooth functions, there are bijections which are not diffeomorphisms.
John Douma's $f(x) = x^3$ is a counterexample.

Comment: The last fact is wrong as stated for the category of topological spaces (it has continuous inverse $\sqrt[3]{x}$). John's example if for differentiable manifolds

Comment: true true, let's find another thing

Comment: The usual example is $\exp(2\pi i (-)) : [0,1) \to S^1$